# Why there is a dependence between the factors on the same column?

Tags: r, multicollinearity, lm

I found that the lm model I have trained has some NAs in the coeficents, and it is in the factor columns. So I have [searched for aliases](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/alias.html) an I have found that some factor values depend on the other factor values on the same column; for a better understanding I have written the following example:

```
dt <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("m", 1.75,  -2, 8),
                          c("m", 1.85,  -1, 10),
                          c("m", 1.65,  -3, 12),
                          c("m", 1.95,  -2, 11),
                          c("f", 1.75,  2, 10),
                          c("f", 1.85,  1, 11),
                          c("f", 1.65,  3, 8),
                          c("f", 1.95,  2, 20),
                          c("u", 1.75,  -2, 1),
                          c("u", 1.85,  -1, 17),
                          c("u", 1.65,  -3, 9),
                          c("u", 1.95,  -2, 16)
                          ))
colnames(dt) <- c("x4", "x1", "x3", "x2")
dt$x4 <- as.factor(dt$x4)
dt$x1 <- as.numeric(dt$x1)
dt$x2 <- as.numeric(dt$x2)
dt$x3 <- as.factor(dt$x3)
summary(dt)

model <- lm(x1 ~ x3 + x4 + x2, data = dt)
model

alias(model)
```

output

```
Model :
x1 ~ x3 + x4 + x2

Complete :
    (Intercept) x3-1 x32 x3-2 x33 x3-3 x4m x2
x4u  0           1    0   1    0   1   -1   0
```

What I do not understand is why there is an alias/dependence between the factors on the same column (like x4u and x4m)?

---

If this means that the model is bad/wrong, how to improve it?

Comment: This is just *illustrated* with R, it isn't about how to use R. It should be considered on topic here, IMO.

Comment: In your group f you got the factor values 2, 1, 3, 2 for the variable $x_3$. These values do not occur in any other group. Is that correct? There is no typo that the negative and positive values should be the same? And also this vector $x_3$ should really be considered as a categorical variable rather than a continuous variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is to provide a more graphic representation of Randa's answer.

*Q: why is there a dependence between factors on the same column?*

*A: They are not the same column. The different **values** in a factor each represent a different column*

If we split the two factors into the 6 and 3 dummy vectors that they actually represent then you can better view the dependency:

$$
\newcommand\coolunder[2]{ {\smash{%
\underbrace{#2\phantom{\begin{matrix} %
\end{matrix}}}_{{#1}}}}}
%
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\overbrace{\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1 \end{matrix}}^{intercept}&
\overbrace{\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\color{red}1&0\\
0&0&0&\color{red}1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\color{red}1\\
0&0&0&0&\color{red}1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
\coolunder{ x3-1}{0}
&\coolunder{x3-2}{1}
&\coolunder{x3-3}{0}
&\coolunder{x31}{0}
&\coolunder{x32}{0}
&\coolunder{x33}{0}
\end{matrix}}^{x3}
&\overbrace{\begin{matrix}\color{red}1&0&0\\
\color{red}1&0&0\\
\color{red}1&0&0\\
\color{red}1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&\color{red}1\\
0&0&\color{red}1\\
0&0&\color{red}1\\
\coolunder{x4m}{0}
&\coolunder{x4f}{0}
&\coolunder{x4u}{\color{red}1}
\end{matrix}}^{x4}
&\overbrace{\begin{matrix}8\\10\\12\\11\\10\\11\\8\\20\\1\\17\\9\\16 \end{matrix}}^{x2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And alias shows that the column x4u can be written as the sum of the columns: $$(x4u) = (intercept) -(x31) -(x32) -(x33) -(x4m)$$

---

Note that with these factors you normally also have the intercept term as a sum of the factor columns:

$$\begin{array}\\(intercept) &= (x3-1)+(x3-2)+(x3-3)+(x31)+(x32)+(x33)\\(intercept) &= (x4m)+(x4f)+(x4u)\end{array}$$

but the lm model automatically drops one of the dummy variables in each factor. Which you can also see in the alias output which does not contain x3-1 and x4f

---

See also the function

```
> model.matrix(model)

   (Intercept) x3-2 x3-3 x31 x32 x33 x4m x4u x2
1            1    1    0   0   0   0   1   0  8
2            1    0    0   0   0   0   1   0  2
3            1    0    1   0   0   0   1   0  4
4            1    1    0   0   0   0   1   0  3
5            1    0    0   0   1   0   0   0  2
6            1    0    0   1   0   0   0   0  3
7            1    0    0   0   0   1   0   0  8
8            1    0    0   0   1   0   0   0  7
9            1    1    0   0   0   0   0   1  1
10           1    0    0   0   0   0   0   1  6
11           1    0    1   0   0   0   0   1  9
12           1    1    0   0   0   0   0   1  5
```

And also note that the `as.numeric(dt$x2)` did not go well (it copies the level-orders and not the levels). You can solve this by using `as.numeric(paste(dt$x2))`

Answer (score 2):

Nonzero entries in the "complete" matrix show that those terms are linearly dependent on x4u. This alludes to the fact that they are highly correlated. One way of improving your model is to eliminate for instance x3-1, x3-2, x3-3 and x2 independent variables from the model; leaving them in your model results to an increase in the variance of regression coefficients.